# Integrating PHP/General HTTP Request with Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rudy on Rails backend which I use because it has some libraries that other languages don't have. I'm trying to use it as a web service/backend and accept requests from PHP/general HTTP request pages. It should be very simple - hopefully, accept a JSON object and respond with a JSON object. Rails seems to default to a RJS/ non-standard client side request.

Ideally, I'd have a php generated jquery/html page send a JSON object to a ruby on rails page and have the ruby on rails page respond with a different JSON object.

Obviously, I'm not very familiar with Rails, but I would like to use it. I know it isn't a good idea to attempt to integrate Ruby on Rails with PHP. In essence, I'd like to run ruby simply as a web service for the same purpose.

I suppose in the abstract, this would be how to integrate rails as a backend with other client side technologies.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache I would recommend you to serve those application from different [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html). For example, you can have:

- PHP based website => www.example.com
- Rails Web Service => service.example.com/wsdl

This will allow you to isolate PHP and Ruby configurations and you'll avoid conflicts between them.

The communication between apps will be made as usual.

> If you have any question regarding Apache or VirtualHost you can ask in [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or read some great tutorials at [Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/) or [Linode Library](http://library.linode.com/)

Comment: This _may_ end up giving you headaches with same-origin issues, if you are calling the ROR system via Javascript sent to the client from the PHP system... something to be careful about.

Comment: I can't see a JS "same-origin" issue because you're accessing each of them with a different URL, although both applications are served by the same Apache instance,